# How to detect bluetooth input from external scanner

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have an issue.

I am trying to integrate a scanner (which is acting like an external bluetooth keyboard), to my android application.

**The problem is** that I can't figure it out **how can I detect when the keyboard send the message to my application.**

The scanner is working, and the text is displayed inside any edit text, but I want to make some modifications to it.

I tried to search for an intent filter to enable a receiver for the event that is triggered when the bluetooth device sent the message, but I can't find a good one.

Anybody can point me to a direction?

Thanks,
Arkde